# Played the game fairly vs played a fair game

Tags: exam-questions

Is there any grammatical error in either of the following sentence or they both are correct and interchangeably usable ?

> Both the teams **played the game fairly**.
>
> Both the teams **played a fair game**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both the teams played the game fairly.

Here, **fairly** describes the **play** of the game. This means that both teams followed the rules properly. It makes no mention of the quality of their performances.

> Both the teams played a fair game.

Here, **fair** describes the quality of the **game**. This means that both teams showed reasonable skill and strategy in their performances. It does not imply anything about fouls or penalties.

Answer (score 1):

@Davo gave a good answer, I want to add:

- Both the teams played the game **fairly**. - answers the question "**How did they play the game?**" This can be thought of as "**[legitimately](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/legitimately)**" - *in a way that conforms to the law or to rules.* "**[Fairly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fairly)**" means *in the right way*.
- Both the teams played a **fair** game. - answers the question "**What kind of game did they play?**" "**[fair](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fair)**" means *right; reasonable*.

> If a game or competition is **fair**, it is done *according to the rules*, "**It was a fair fight.**"